# Displaying an "overlay" node in JavaFx ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with a surprisingly simple thing..

I have a large Pane in a scrollpane, and I am trying to display one of its children in the top-left corner of the scrollpane, regardless of where the viewport is scrolled.

I've tried to calculate the position with hValue and vValue of the Scrollpane, but couldn't quite get the result I wanted.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Blast. I figured it out myself.

```
Bounds b = container.getBoundsInParent();
node.setX(scroll.getHValue() * (b.getMaxX() - scroll.getWidth()));
node.setY(scroll.getVValue() * (b.getMaxY() - scroll.getHeight()));
```

... will display the node in the top left corner.